# How to set QTableWidget height under 70

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtablewidget, minimum-size

I am using Qt5.3.0 with Qt Creator. I want to have a really small QTableWidget which the widget height can be 10. I will make sizePolicy to expanded so that it can be expanded to a larger number.

**This is what I did:**

1. Create a Qt application with MainWindow.

2. Drag a QTableWidget in MainWindow.

3. Apply a verticalLayout to Mainwindow.

4. Build and Run.

I will get the table but I cannot make it shorter than 70 by adjusting the window's size with the rightbottom corner triangle thing (resize triangle?).

I've also tried to subclass QTableWidget and return sizeHint but it doesn't help.
What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the minimum height of the `QTableWidget` to 10. By default it has some kind of an internal minimum height and it behaves like you described.

```
tableWidget->setMinimumHeight(10);
```

or just set it in QtCreator UI editor property.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works. However when I put it, together with a QPushButton above it, into a QFrame, it then appears back to 70 height. And even if I set the minimumsize of the frame, if I call my QTableWidget setMinimumHeight to 0 by code, and resize the mainwindow to 0,0, the fixed height QPushButton becomes a 3~5px height tiny button and a small 20px QTableWidget. Why?

Comment: should I post a new thread for this question? I put a push button and a table widget into a frame and add a v-layout to this frame. in my MainWindow::MainWindow() I put 
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pushButton->setMinimumHeight(25);
    ui->tableWidget->setMinimumHeight(0);
//    ui->frame->setMinimumHeight(25);
    this->resize(0, 0); this will cause my table to 70 height again. and if I remove the comment mark, when I drag the window to bigger I will see the table lay over the button!

Comment: A widget needs at least 1 pixel of height. If you set 0, then it resets the height to the default internal settings. Set the height to not less then 1. Setting it to 0 would be like hiding it and there is `hide()` for that.